# file_put_contents for a pdf isn't working

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve a variety of attachments, save them to storage, then call them when needed by a web page. The images (not my design) are stored as Varbinary in a SQL server. All attachments this works except for PDF files. I get this error: the contents of this file have been damaged. I'm reading directly off of the server, so it's not an issue with the front end. .xlsx, .txt, .docx all seem to work fine. I also seem to have issues with .jpg showing a partial image.

```
$Extension = rtrim(explode('.',$Name)[1]);
$FileName = "Attachments/".$UniqueName.'.'.$Extension;
file_put_contents($FileName, $Code);
```

Comment: Is it conceivable that the image(s) for the pdfs are.... damaged? :)

Comment: I doubt the issue is with file_put_contents, more likely the value of $Code is invalid.

Comment: @cale_b I thought the same thing. I verified the $Code against a 3rd party and the PDF shows up correctly. That's why I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. my php.ini file was restricting the number of characters it can return. I increased the size and that solved my issue.

```
mssql.textlimit = 1048576
mssql.textsize = 1048576
```